# Why in my case is return not ending the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code I'm using for sticky header some other things.

```js
function stickyHeader(index) {
  $('.worship-items .collapse').eq(index).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
    shouldReturn = true;
    var header = $('.card-header').eq(index);
    header.removeClass('fixed-top');
    header.css('z-index', 0);

    // The return here is not ending the function?
    return false;
  });

  var shouldReturn = false;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if (shouldReturn == false) {
      var header = $('.card-header').eq(index);
      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

      if (scroll >= $('.card').eq(index).offset().top) {
        header.addClass('fixed-top');
        header.css('z-index', 10);
      } else {
        header.removeClass('fixed-top');
        header.css('z-index', 0);
      }
    } else {
      // return here is not ending the function.
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

For some reason, the `return` is not ending the function. I've learned that return does not end the function if it's in a `while`, `for`, `foreach`, or `loop` but I'm not using that here.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: A return **always** terminates the function it is inside.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't end the function"? Are you going inside that `else` statement? Also, it will only terminate *the callback* you've given to `$(window).scroll` - that's the function `return` belongs to, it won't terminate a different function, if that's what you expect.

Comment: To expand on @Taplar's comment, you're returning from the `hidden.bs.collapse` and `scroll` event handlers, not the outer `stickyHeader()` function. That said, the event handlers are, for all intents and purposes, asynchronous of the `stickyHeader()` function, so I don't see what you're expecting any `return` to do - the outer function has long finished executing anything when the events actually fire.

Comment: Okay, so that makes sense, but is there any way I can "terminate" the `stickyHeader()`?

Comment: As Rory already said, the `stickHeader` method has already ended.  The event handlers are executing independently

Comment: So with that in mind, this is coming across as an XY problem.  What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Taplar the reason I'm using the return is so after the classes are removed from `card-header`, the function ends so it does not add the classes back.

Comment: Then you need to conditionally `off()` the event handlers you are adding.  https://api.jquery.com/off

Comment: @Taplar Okay, i'll try that.

Comment: After looking over the code I've typed, I realized I get the result I should be expecting. So the code is working perfectly as typed, thanks.